# Is my compiler optimizing away proper code into useless crashing code?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that displays the PID of the owning process of all threads in a system in multiple message boxes.

```
void CheckProcess()
{
LPCSTR blahzix;
HANDLE tsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
THREADENTRY32 tentry;
tentry.dwSize = sizeof (tentry);
BOOL CRec = Thread32First(tsnap, &tentry);
GetLastError();
while (CRec)
{
    blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID;
    MessageBox (NULL, NULL, blahzix, MB_OK);
    CRec = Thread32Next(tsnap, &tentry);
}
CloseHandle(tsnap);
}
```

I was confused about why this wasn't working for a while so I opened it up in OllyDBG and found out that the code for `MessageBox`was having its third parameter receive the PID data directly instead of receiving an address which has the PID stored as a string, resulting in an access violation when the `MessageBox` function tries to access data stored at 00000004. If I remove the line `blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID;` and append the third line to look like this: `LPCSTR blahzix = "anything";` then instead of crashing `MessageBox` properly displays a messagebox with the title anything.

Why does this happen? Am I correct in thinking that the compiler decides "variable blahzix isn't used anywhere except in this messagebox function and it always equals tentry.th32OwnerProcessID so they might as well be the same variable, I'll just get rid of it and make messagebox use that variable instead."

EDIT: Let me rephrase my question. If `LPCSTR blahzix = "fdisaf";` uses the = operator and the = operator is supposed to change the value of the variable on the left to the value of the data or variable on the right, then how come it's use to create a string for blahzix is valid? Since blahzix is apparently actually [a pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I would assume the = operator should only change where the variable points to instead of changing the contents in it. How come using the = operator in this instance changes the data of the string that it points to and using it in this instance: `blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID;` changes the data of the pointer instead of the data of the string? Shouldn't the = operator change one or the other? How can I make the = operator specify which data I want to change?

Comment: `blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID` doesn't convert the pid to a string - it just writes the pid to a local variable, leaving `blahzix` pointing to an address that equals the pid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID;
```

doesn't convert the integer process id to a string.  It merely writes the process id as the address that `blahzix` points to.  You don't own memory at this address so attempting to display a string from it results in undefined behaviour.  A crash is likely.

To display the process id as a string via a `MessageBox`, you need to convert it to a `char` array.  Given C++11 support you can do this by changing

```
blahzix = tentry.th32OwnerProcessID;
MessageBox (NULL, NULL, blahzix, MB_OK);
```

to

```
std::string s = std::to_string(tentry.th32OwnerProcessID);
char const *pchar = s.c_str(); 
MessageBox (NULL, NULL, pchar, MB_OK);
```

Alternatively, if you're limited to using C (the question is tagged as C++ but the code is all C), you could use

```
char str[12];
sprintf(str, "%d", tentry.th32OwnerProcessID);
MessageBox (NULL, NULL, str, MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 4):

`THREADENTRY32::th32OwnerProcessID` is a `DWORD`, not a string. Assigning it to a pointer and treating it as a string does not make sense. It's also invalid (a constraint violation without an explicit cast); I'm surprised how/why this even compiled.

Don't blame your own errors on the compiler. Compiler bugs are very, very rare.

Comment: I'm using -fpermissive, might be why it compiled.